# Need to preg_replace "/|/"

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$title = preg_replace("/|/", "", $title);
```

In case you're wondering what "/|/" is it's the sign on the same key as backslash, except you use the Shift key to use it.

It doesn't do it if you just do it as it is in the example. There must be some way of removing it.

Comment: Why not just `str_replace()` ? (btw: `|` has a special meaning, escape it)

Comment: Some input and expected output is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's going to do it either. It's not about the function. There must be some kind of workaround for it to be replaced/removed.

Comment: It's in the example. I want "/|/" to be removed. There's something about | that it just doesn't get removed.

Comment: @VitalSigns Do you want the pipe `|` to be removed? Then you need to escape it since it has a special meaning in regex. It means "OR". So "/A|B/" will match either A or B. Now go use `/\|/` or as Rizier123 said, use a simple `str_replace('|', '', $title)`

Comment: as Rizier123 said you'll need to escape it with an `\\` before like `"/\|/"`

Comment: @Rizier Can you show my how to escape it? Something like this? "/\|/"

Comment: Yes, thank you. I totally forgot that it means "or" in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exacly if you want to remove just the pipe `|` or literally `/|/` so here are two examples:

```
$title = "hi | there";
$text = preg_replace("/\|/", "", $title);
echo $text; //"hi there";


$title = "hi /|/ there";
$text = preg_replace("/\/\|\//", "", $title);
echo $text; //hi there
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use a regex for a simple string replacement. Sounds like a lot of unneccesarry overhead. You should just use `str_replace` if you just want to replace simple strings.

```
$text = str_replace('|', '', $title);
```

Of course, you could also use regexes, but then you have to escape the `|` char, because it means OR. This would result in something like this

```
$title = preg_replace('/\|/', '', $text);
```